# python extract data columns and put them side by side

Tags: python, extract, multiple-columns

Good morning, I'm a new python user and I have some experience with MATLAB. To practice I would like to write a script that would also help me during my job. I have a large file and I would like to extract some of the columns and put the side by side (the columns have all the same lenght).
So, I start from a situation like this
:

```
                            Great amount of text and numbers
                           1         2         3         4         5
                           O         O         O         O         O
      SpecialText --       text      text      text      text      text
       1 1   A  1A         col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       2        2A         col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       3        2BX        col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       4        2BY        col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       5        2BZ        col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       6 2   B  3A         col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       7        3AX        col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
       8        3AY        col1      col2      col3      col4      col5

                           6         7         8         9         10
                           O         O         O         O         O
     SpecialText --        text      text      text      text      text
       1 1   A  1A         col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       2        2A         col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       3        2BX        col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       4        2BY        col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       5        2BZ        col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       6 2   B  3A         col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       7        3AX        col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
       8        3AY        col6      col7      col8      col9      col10
```

And I want to obtain something like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 ...
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 ...
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 ...
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 ...
...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

My question is really simple. Is this doable for a beginner? Are there any libraries that I can use to ease this work?
Sorry for my inexperience and thanks in advance.

EDIT: the starting file is a .txt file
EDIT2: modified the starting file for clarity

Comment: Pandas would probably be a useful library

Comment: If you have a csv file you can really easy achieve this with pandas

Comment: Thanks to both, the starting file is a .txt file, I'll try to convert it to a .csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below program

```py
import re
result={}
with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    insidedatablock=False
    line=f.readline()
    while line!='':
        if line.strip().startswith("SpecialText"):
            insidedatablock=True
        if line.strip()=='':
            insidedatablock=False
        if insidedatablock==True:
            cols=re.split("\s+",line.strip())
            if cols[0].isdigit() and len(cols)>=7:
                if cols[0] in result:
                    result[cols[0]]+=cols[-5:]
                else:
                    result[cols[0]]=cols[-5:]
        line=f.readline()
for i in result:
    print(" ".join(result[i]))
```

This prints below with given txt file.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
```

Comment: Thanks you very, this program is a bit above my abilities therefore I'wouldn't be able to write it myself. There's just a little issue: the file is big and the program extracts also other values, maybe starting the program from the line `SpecialText` will resolve the problem.

Comment: Okay. I have updated the program above. now it will search for `SpecialText`, once it found, it will start reading data until it finds empty line (there is an empty line after 8th row) once done it will search for next `SpecialText` and repeat above till end of file. Basically, I assume data is surrounded by a line starting with `SpecialText` and an empty line.